# What is "com.example.helloWorld(androidTest)" package in Android Studio project structure

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I recently installed AS and noticed this com.example.helloWorld(androidTest) package. I searched about but seems it's not a question for people! so sorry if its to easy

Comment: That's my answer. If put it as a question out of disbelief. I rephrase: Automated testing project!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default *sourceSet*[1] that is used for on-device unit testing. This is the package where are all of your tests live. You could, for example, create a subclass of one of Android's `TestCase`[2] classes here, and execute it and your other tests using the `connectedAndroidTest` gradle task. Note that this is different from the new experimental unit test support, which do not run on a device and require more pure Java/junit tests.

#### More info

[1] http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Basics-and-Configuration

[2] http://developer.android.com/reference/junit/framework/TestCase.html